# P2P File Synchronization in Android

Tags: android, p2p

I am working on a project which has to work with some android devices, and there is no server. I need to maintain a file which will contain the phone number of users along with their emails and IP Addresses(has to be dynamic).I am going to use `2D Array` (please suggest if any good option is available).

I want to update the file with every user in case any change is made by any user. I am thinking of using the `WiFi-Direct API`, and it seems to be a good option as well.

Is there any way by which i can do it via internet so that even if a user is not within the same `WiFi` he/she can update the file with other users.

Comment: You should use Firebase server its totally free

Comment: i need to keep it p2p without the server